# Django model ForeignKey backwards referencing and AttributeError when trying to use ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to build models for a database that reads an .xml file with a given data format, and I'm having trouble at setting backwards compatibility.

My models are

```
from django.db import models

class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='', unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')


    countries = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Continent',
        through='Country',
    )


class Country(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='', unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='', unique=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, default='', related_name='related_name')
```

and as you can see, I'm a bit clueless when it comes to related_name. Anyhow, running a test that has parsed through this data gives me the error

> AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'

but I'm not sure how I should approach to eliminate it.

The test tries to run

```
fi = europe.countries.get(code="fi")
```

and raises an exception if it can't find anything for it (the data holds every continent and country), so the backwards referencing is not functional as of yet.

Edit:
This is the part of the test that is raising an exception

```
def testCountryThroughContinent(self):

        europe = Continent.objects.get(code="eu")
        try:
             sw = europe.countries.get(code="sw")
        except:
             self.assertTrue(False, "Getting country failed. Did you remember that countries should be accessed through attribute countries?")
        self.assertEqual(sw.name, "Sweden", "Getting a country from a continent")
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve in real life here?  Given the names, your approach looks overly complicated

Comment: At this stage I'm trying to just make the models for the database, and I've been given a premade test function to make sure it works as it should. I have only one part raisin an exception now, I'll edit it into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using FK to continent from country you don't need additional M2M

```
from django.db import models

class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='', unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='', unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='', unique=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, related_name='countries')
```

Don't forget to do `makemigrations` and apply them after that

Comment: I need Continent class to have the attribute "countries", though, where the countries within the continent would be stored by code

Comment: @Grak Yes, I understand that, and this is achieved by adding ForeignKey in Country model which you have already done. If you use this models you can do `fi = europe.countries.get(code="fi")`

Comment: Ah, so the related_name just had to be 'countries' in order for the Continent class to get the attribute, I see. Thanks! (hadn't noticed the name change before)