# m2m 'through' field in django models throwing this error: 'M2M field' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hey guys I am trying to add a m2m `through` field to have assistants to my 'Department' model to call like `department.assistants.all()`, but while doing so, I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'`.

This is my model:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    id                  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user                = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assistants          = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Assistants', related_name='dep_assistants', 
                            symmetrical=False)

class Assistants(models.Model):
    id                  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    department          = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='of_department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assistant           = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='dt_assistant', 
                            verbose_name="Department Assistant", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am pretty new to this concept. Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming the `ForeignKey` from `Assistants` is colliding with m2m from `Department`. This db structure doesn't even seem to make sense.

Comment: yes seems like the issue from my comment above. If you'd search for `_m2m_reverse_name_cache`, there's already some questiosn dealing with the exact same situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432609/django-model-foreignkey-backwards-referencing-and-attributeerror-when-trying-to

Comment: What is your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` and which version of Django are you using?

Comment: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is my custom user model which takes email for login instead of username.. and I'm using Django 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have defined your models the queries seem too confusing. Try how models are defined below and then try the query.

You did not mention the through_field attribute in the many to many field definition. check the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

```py
class Department(models.Model):
    # i think this is not needed. Also id is a protected keyword in python.
    # id                  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user                = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assistants          = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Assistants', 
                                                 related_name='departments', through_fields=("department", "assistant"))

# model name should never be prural. It is singluar becuase it is the name of the object.
class Assistant(models.Model):
    # i think this is not needed. Also id is a protected keyword in python.
    # id                  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    department          = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assistant           = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="Department Assistant", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


# how to query assistants from departments
# you will get objects of User model
qs = department.assistants.all()


# how to query departments from assistants
# you will get objects of Department model
qs = user.departments.all()


# If you want to query the Assistant model

# from department object
qs = department.assistant_set.all()

# from assistant object
qs = user.assistant_set.all()

# in either case you will get the objects of Assistant model
for i in qs:
    print(i.added, i.department, i.assistant)
```

Try this and let me know if you still get the error.

My suggestion is to name the `assistant` field on the Assistant model as `user`. This way you will not need to define `through_field` on the many to many field.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Does using `through_field ` got any disadvantages?

Comment: no disadvantages at all. But the way your models are structured that field should be called `user` instead of `assistant` since the model is called `Assistant`. An assistant object has a user and department as members makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If one assistant relates to only one department - this is relation one-to-many. (One department has many assistants) In code would be:

```
class Assistant(models.Model):
    ...
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
```

No need for a special reference on Department. To get all assistants:

```
assistants = models.Assistant.objects.filter(department=department)
```

Or create a property on a class Department:

```
@property
def assistants(self):
    return models.Assistant.objects.filter(department=self)
```

If one assistant relates to many departments (and each department has many assistants), it is many-to-many relationship and there should be additional class between them:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    assistant = models.ForeignKey(Assistant)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)

class Department(models.Model):
    ...
    assignment= models.ForeignKey(Assignment)

class Assistant(models.Model):
    ...
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
```

So here to query assistants of the department:

```
assistants = models.Assistant.objects.filter(
    assignment__in=models.Assignment.objects.filter(
        department=department
    )
)
```